# Looking for a C#-REPL compatible for LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, read-eval-print-loop

I tried several REPL add-ons for Visual Studio 10,

but non of them have compatibility for LINQ expressions.

Would save me a lot of time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a VS add-in, but I recommend [`LINQPad`](http://www.linqpad.net/)

It's got great support for LINQ and supports the Entity Framework well too.

Comment: thanks Nicholas.
do you know if there is a run-time REPL for c#, in which I can use my existing variables and methods while they are running?